# How to import dynamic Javascript element from a website to Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, cryptocurrency

I am trying to import a current price from a website that utilizes JavaScript to dynamically update the price of a crypto coin using the =ImportXML function in google sheets. Below is what I have tried but obviously it is not correct. Any ideas on how to pull a price of a coin from the URL mentioned below?

This method works with other websites that dont automatically update the price live on scree but it seems being a dynamic field does not allow this method to work.

> =IMPORTXML(F3,"//div[@class='mb-1 d-flex flex-column lh-1']")
>
> > F3=https://poocoin.app/tokens/0x864397b060a2210e9ded2e9a8d63cd7a83eb0ef0

Comment: Google Sheets is not meant to provide true web scraping capabilities - use a proper API instead.

Answer (score 1):

Would advise using a proper API to get the coins prices.

Websites are not meant for bot consumption, they can change at any moment and force you to re implement everything again.

You could try this endpoint instead albeit it might be missing smaller/poop coins? `=IMPORTDATA("https://cryptoprices.cc/BTC/")`

CoinGecko also has a good API which you could try using with only slightly more effort

`=importJSON("https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&ids=bitcoin","0.current_price")`

Answer (score 0):

You might be having problems because the url you're querying is behind a DDos protector